# How to Create DropDown list with 13 days bunch

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Please help me,I want to create dropdown with 13 days of bunch as an option.
for example : 
2017-02-05 00:00:00.000 2017-02-18 23:59:59.000
2017-02-19 00:00:00.000 2017-03-04 23:59:59.000 
........

U can give me a soltion in any technology(MVC code,JQuery,JavaScript).

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time to read the help files and understand what is an appropriate question on this site (it is not a code writing service)

Comment: I want This : <option>2017-02-19 00:00:00.000 2017-03-04 23:59:59.000</option>

Comment: I have No idea please help. @MitchWheat

Comment: Every option add with 13 days bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Create a Mothod or Extension method of datetime,I used Extension method

```
 public static class DateTime_Extension
{
    public static List<DateTime> ConvertToDateTimeWithDifference(this DateTime startDate, int value, DateTime lastDate)
    {
        List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
        while (startDate <= lastDate)
        {
            dateList.Add(startDate);
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(value);
        }
        return dateList;
    }
}
```

And Use Like this (here 13 is difference as parameter)
and generate dateList from today to next 5 year you can change parameter

```
 DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
 var dateList = startDate.ConvertToDateTimeWithDifference(13, startDate.AddYears(5));
```

Comment: Thanks it help me please can you help that how can I use here(on controler)   public static List<DateTime> ConvertToDateTimeWithDifference()
        {

            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
            var dateList = startDate.ConvertToDateTimeWithDifference(13, startDate.AddYears(5));
            return dateList;

        }

Comment: Thanks Bro Its Working Properly @Dharmesh Kumar Laxkar

Comment: How Can I Bind datelist to dropdown ?   I Tried this way     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TDate,new SelectList(ViewBag.DateRange as List<SelectListItem>, "Value", "Text")). please help

Comment: DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
 var dateList = startDate.ConvertToDateTimeWithDifference(13, startDate.AddYears(5));